# .bst function to strip LaTeX command from string

Tags: bibtex, syntax

Is there a preexisting `.bst` command to stip all LaTeX commands from a string?

For example, if the string on the top of the stack is "`Hello \textsc{ladies}`" I'd like to replace it with just "`Hello ladies`".

Comment: Are you after a BibTeX style with no added formatting, or one to remove formatting that's already in the input. The latter seems pretty complex, as things like accents will go wrong.

Comment: Remove existing formatting

Comment: That sounds very tricky indeed. BibTeX cannot expand TeX macros, so you are left having to search through letter by letter for `\foo`. You thus have to either make some assumptions about formatting commands or about accents, _etc._ I suspect this will not be robust however it's done. What we certainly need is a bit more context: for example, do you have a list of formatting that may appear?

Comment: Well, yeah in general I want to remove any markup like \textsc{} or accents (e.g. \"{}).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bst` is the file extension used by the compiler `bibtex`. BibTeX doesn't have this functionality. To modify the input file you can write a small script (perl, shell etc.) providing this functionality.

Comment: Sorry but this answer is not a good answer, not in a current state. The second part about `\def` is confusing: where should one put it? (I don't think I'm unexperienced LaTeX user, but I would have hard time using that advice.)

Comment: @tohecz: I know. My aim was the reducing of the unanswered list. However there is no way with `bibtex` ;-). I switch the answer to a cw one. Please feel free to edit them.